# How to Connect the Apache Camel with the MSK Schema Registry

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, apache-camel

I have created a schema in MSK of AWS GLUE, but I cannot able to configure it with the Producer of the Application.

**Schema Created in MKS:**

[Schema Created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsk3a.png)

**Kafka Config**:

```
class KafkaConfig {

    @Value("${brokerHost}")
    String brokerHost;

    @Value("${saslMechanism}")
    String saslMechanism;
    @Value("${securityProtocol}")
    String securityProtocol;
    @Value("${brokerConfig}")
    String brokerConfig;
    @Autowired
    CamelContext camelContext;

    @Bean
    public KafkaConfiguration kafkaConfiguration() {
        KafkaConfiguration kafkaConfiguration = new KafkaConfiguration();
        kafkaConfiguration.setBrokers(brokerHost);
        kafkaConfiguration.setSaslMechanism(saslMechanism);
        kafkaConfiguration.setSecurityProtocol(securityProtocol);
        kafkaConfiguration.setSaslJaasConfig(brokerConfig);
        return kafkaConfiguration;
    }

    @Bean(name = "appKafkaProducer")
    public KafkaComponent kafkaComponentProducer() throws Exception {
        KafkaComponent kafkaComponentProducer = new KafkaComponent();
        kafkaComponentProducer.setConfiguration(kafkaConfiguration());;
        camelContext.addComponent("appKafkaProducer", kafkaComponentProducer);
        return kafkaComponentProducer;
    }

    @Bean(name = "appKafkaConsumer")
    public KafkaComponent kafkaComponentConsumer() {
        KafkaComponent kafkaComponentConsumer = new KafkaComponent();
        kafkaComponentConsumer.setConfiguration(kafkaConfiguration());
        camelContext.addComponent("appKafkaConsumer", kafkaComponentConsumer);
        return kafkaComponentConsumer;
    }




}
```

**Producer Route:**

```
<get uri="/refresh">
    <description>Refresh the Route</description>
    <route id="refreshRoute">
        <doTry>
        
            <to uri="appKafkaProducer:Checking" />
            <setBody>
                <constant>ok</constant>
            </setBody>
            <doCatch>
                <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                <to uri="bean:commonsExchangeUtil?method=setErrorResponse(500, 'Internal Server Error', ${exception.message}, *)" />
            </doCatch>
        </doTry>
    </route>
</get>
```

I checked the offical documentation of the Camel, but cannot able to find suitable approach

What are the Configuration that i need to add so that i can able to configure the producer with the schema so that we can validate

Comment: was this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding [additionalProperties](https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/kafka-component.html#_component_option_additionalProperties) for kafka component as key-value pairs and set the properties specified in [AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/validate-evolve-and-control-schemas-in-amazon-msk-and-amazon-kinesis-data-streams-with-aws-glue-schema-registry/#:%7E:text=properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,GENERIC_RECORD.getName())%3B)